# Find rotation matrix to align two vectors

Tags: python, rotation

I try to find the rotation matrix to align two vectors.

I have a vector A = [ax, ay, az] and I would like to align it on the vector B = [1, 0, 0] (x-axis unit vector).

I found the following explanation and tried to implement it:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d/897677#897677

```
def align_vectors(a, b):
     v = np.cross(a, b)
     s = np.linalg.norm(v)
     c = np.dot(a, b)

     v1, v2, v3 = v
     h = 1 / (1 + c)

     Vmat = np.array([[0, -v3, v2],
                      [v3, 0, -v1],
                      [-v2, v1, 0]])

     R = np.eye(3, dtype=np.float64) + Vmat + (Vmat.dot(Vmat) * h)
     return R
```

When I apply it to find the rotation of a point, this is what I have :

```
x_axis = np.array([1, 0, 0], dtype=np.float64)
direction = np.array([-0.02, 1.004, -0.02], dtype=np.float64)
Ralign = align_vectors(x_axis, direction)
point = 1000 * np.array([-0.02, 1.004, -0.02], dtype=np.float64) # Point in the direction of the unit vector
result = Ralign.dot(point)
```

The resulting point is not aligned with the unit vector.

Comment: The answer in math exchange assumes `a` and `b` are unit vectors. You need redo the math to include the length in the calculation. or normalize them first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to rotate ONE vector `a` to align with `b`, not the entire coordinate contain that vector, use simple vector projection and the length of `a`:

```
a_norm = np.linalg.norm(a)
b_norm = np.linalg.norm(b)
result = b * a_norm / b_norm
```

The following fixes the issue in the question that input are not unit vector by vector normalization.

```py
def align_vectors(a, b):
    b = b / np.linalg.norm(b) # normalize a
    a = a / np.linalg.norm(a) # normalize b
    v = np.cross(a, b)
    # s = np.linalg.norm(v)
    c = np.dot(a, b)
    if np.isclose(c, -1.0):
        return -np.eye(3, dtype=np.float64)

    v1, v2, v3 = v
    h = 1 / (1 + c)

    Vmat = np.array([[0, -v3, v2],
                  [v3, 0, -v1],
                  [-v2, v1, 0]])

    R = np.eye(3, dtype=np.float64) + Vmat + (Vmat.dot(Vmat) * h)
    return R
```

The algorithm also fixes another edge case:
If the function gets called with two parallel vectors with opposite directions `h` will evalute to `inf` and R will contain only `nan`s.

```py
align_vectors(np.array([1,0,0]), np.array([-1,0,0]))
```

This gets caught by comparing `c` to -1 and returning the negative identity matrix.
testing:

```py
def angle(a, b):
    """Angle between vectors"""
    a = a / np.linalg.norm(a)
    b = b / np.linalg.norm(b)
    return np.arccos(a.dot(b))

point = np.array([-0.02, 1.004, -0.02])
direction = np.array([1., 0., 0.])
rotation = align_vectors(point, direction)

# Rotate point in align with direction. The result vector is aligned with direction
result = rotation.dot(point)
print(result)
print('Angle:', angle(direction, point)) # 0.0
print('Length:', np.isclose(np.linalg.norm(point), np.linalg.norm(result))) # True


# Rotate direction by the matrix, result does not align with direction but the angle between the original vector (direction) and the result2 are the same.
result2 = rotation.dot(direction)
print(result2)
print('Same Angle:', np.isclose(angle(point,result), angle(direction,result2))) # True
print('Length:', np.isclose(np.linalg.norm(direction), np.linalg.norm(result2))) # True
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
This method looks very similar to the Rodriguez formula. However,  the sine coefficient is not applied to the skew matrix. Any idea why this form was the recommended one?

Comment: The rotation matrix here align `a` to `b` (project `a` onto `b` and keep the length unchanged). Thus, align the vector space represented by `a` to `b`.  Rodriguez rotate the coordinate system *about* a vector `k`. See [this figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#/media/File:Rodrigues-formula.svg) on Wikipedia. The result vector is aligned with `k`(on wiki) if and only if the input vector is. Draw some graph to see how these vectors related.

Comment: Thanks. I can see the two are related and can be used depending on the information we have available. 
If the second is named "Rodriguez formula", what name is given to the first one?